# PHP - What Host name should we provide in websocket server file

Tags: php, websocket, chat

hello I am trying to implemented a chat application into my website. I have uploaded the files to my online server to check the chatting.The code works fine in the localhost The problem is my server.php don't run. I am running the file through ssh from the terminal. I think I might have problem here

```
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);
```

MY server.php file residing in this directory

```
public_html/domain.com/websocket/server.php
```

Comment: Have you looked after it in the process list ? ( `ps aux | grep server.php` )

Comment: @Loïc 614819   12525  0.0  0.0 333044 12180 pts/1    T    13:27   0:00 php server.php
614819   25457  0.0  0.0 103228   756 pts/1    S+   14:06   0:00 grep server.php

this is what it prints out after running your command

Comment: i THINK I have to supply here my domain name? $Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);

Comment: It seems like the server is running. change the 127.0.0.1 to your domain name yes, kill the process, and restart it.

Comment: @Loïc OK I want to know 1 more thing. The file is in my adddon domain. and the main domain is different one. so should I write  main domain here or the adddon domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73128/discussion-between-mynameisbutt-and-loic).